# How to get the price of a product in onCreate method?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I use in-app-billing in the project. I'm getting item price with

```
String price = inventory.getSkuDetails(CARD25).getPrice();
```

How to get the price of that product in onCreate method?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/16502851/3629732